# Core data simple one-to-one relationship

Tags: core-data

I have a simple core data question.

I set up an employee entity and an employeeDetails entity.  Both have a relationship pointing to the other to form a simple one-to-one relationship.  Each employee has one employeeDetail.

I am able to store new employees and fetch them when needed. My question is how do I store the matching employeeDetails at the same time I store the employee and how do I retrieve the details for a matching employee in the fetch?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you always have an employeeDetail, and it's 1:1, why is it a separate entity?

Comment: Because I keep a large set of the employee data in memory and only need to access the details when the employee row is tapped to view details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigger that goes off on every insert into the employee relvar.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Comment: Trigger is a database concept, as far as I know it does not exist in IOS core-data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by regenerating the class for the entities, core data will add a dynamic variable representing the relationship.  When I store the entities, I create an Employee and EmployeeDetails object and point the employee details field(managed dynamically by core data) to my EmployeeDetails object.

```
- (void)addEmployee :(NSDictionary *)_employee {    

    // Create a new instance of the Employee entity.
    Employee *employee = (Employee *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    EmployeeDetails *employeeDetails = (EmployeeDetails *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EmployeeDetails" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    // Add the new employee
    employee.firstName = [_employee objectForKey:@"first_name"];;
    employee.lastName = [_employee objectForKey:@"last_name"];;
/* --> */   employee.details = employeeDetails;  // Associate with details object

    // Add details
    employeeDetails.address    = [self getValue:[e objectForKey:@"street_address"]];   
    employeeDetails.cellPh     = [self getValue:[e objectForKey:@"cell"]];

    // Save the data
    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"core date save error: %@", error);
    }   
}
```